# How to get the item and subItem on the ListViewControl?

Tags: c#

How to access the files in ListViewControl?
On an initial event, I have a button that lists the necessary files on the lsitView using foreach loop. The control has 2 items: File Name & File Path (subItem)

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo f in d.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f.Name).SubItems.Add(f.DirectoryName.ToString());
}
```

Now, I would like to display each items' full path plus the filename with extensions.

```
foreach(ListViewItem f in lstView1.Items)
{
    Console.Writeline(f.ToString());
}
```

When I get the filename, the output is like below. There are extra string and not the filename.extension only:

> ListViewItem: {sample.txt}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, it is using the SubItems [Text Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
foreach (ListViewItem f in lstProjectFiles.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.SubItems[0].Text);
    Console.WriteLine(f.SubItems[1].Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only loading the file name into the list box, not the FileInfo.

How about cheating a little and storing the FileInfo in the Tag property?

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo f in d.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f.Name).SubItems.Add(f.DirectoryName.ToString()).Tag = f; // Store FileInfo in Tag property
}

...

foreach(ListViewItem f in lstView1.Items)
{
    Console.Writeline(((FileInfo)f.SubItems[0].Tag).FullName);
}
```

Then you can access anything in the FileInfo object later on. Of course you may want to refactor & validate, but this is the gist of one approach you could take.