# Assigning the rows from a listView to a dictionary on button click

Tags: c#, dictionary, listview

Web programmer trying to learn C# here, I'm trying to create a message box that iterates through the remaining rows in a listView on a buttonClick event.

I'm not sure where to start with this. Below are the related methods

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> getDwgData(string [] fileLocs)
    {
        // Create a new instance of Dictionary<string, string>
        var dwgData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Add an entry to the dictionary
        foreach (string fileLoc in fileLocs)
        {
            dwgData[fileLoc] = "REV 1";
        }

        return dwgData;
    }
    // File Dialog Box
    private void selectDWGs_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the dialog and get the result
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = true;
        dialog.Filter = "CAD Drawings: *.dwg | *.dwg";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"T:\";
        dialog.Title = "Please select drawings to be included..";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in getDwgData(dialog.FileNames))
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(entry.Key));
                item.SubItems.Add(entry.Value);
                item.SubItems.Add(entry.Key);

                // Add to the listView
                dwgList.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
    }

    private void runEISD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Pull the remaining data that wasn't deleted from the listView and assign to a dictionary. Call a future method with that data.
    }
```

'''

Please point me in the right direction / advise how I should modify my code to achieve the desired result. I want to achieve this effect when button "runEISD" is clicked.

I've tried this:

```
        private void runEISD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance of Dictionary<string, string>
        foreach(var v in dwgList.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DWG #" + v + "\nRev #"); 
        }
    }
```

I'm successful in getting the row items to display iteratively, but how do I grab the relevant subItems?

Comment: dwgData.Add(fileLoc, "REV 1")

Comment: I plan to add functionality for the string REV1 in the future, it will be obtained from another method. For now it is just a string

Comment: Your code is wrong.  To add a new item to a dictionary use ADD.

Comment: @jdweng What's wrong with assigning directly using the key name as he's doing? Seems a little harsh to say it's *wrong*. Especially if you know you want the last value to win in the case of duplicate key names, because you don't have to check `ContainsKey` first.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get the item and subItem on the ListViewControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918918/how-to-get-the-item-and-subitem-on-the-listviewcontrol)

```
    private void runEISD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance of Dictionary<string, string>
        foreach(ListViewItem v in dwgList.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DWG #" + v.SubItems[0].Text + "\nRev # " + v.SubItems[1].Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you find that a question has already been answered, please vote to close it as a duplicate of that question, rather than linking to it in your answer!